# Is there an English equivalant to the Russian saying "the baker never buys his bread"?

Tags: idiom-requests

I heard a good Russian(?) saying that I like, which is, "the baker never buys his bread," as in, "bakers aren't wealthy people, but at least they always have bread." Kind of like if you were a shop mechanic, at least you'd be able to fix your car when it breaks down.

The problem is, when I use it, people don't understand the idiom, then I have to explain it. Is there something similar in English? I feel like there is.

Comment: I would think the more appropriate phrasing to convey the meaning you want would be something like "*The baker never needs to buy bread*". I can't think of a common idiom off the top of my head but I think this would be more understood than what you're saying... regardless, it doesn't have any implication that the baker is poor, only that his work gives him the bread he needs for the day... and you could argue that, technically, he does pay for the ingredients, so he does still pay for it to some degree.

Comment: Is that actually what the saying means? I take it to be more along the lines of "the baker never buys _his own_ bread" because he knows what's in it.

Comment: @SomethingDark - that it what it sounds like, which is why JFA needs to explain his intent to others, and why his question about a better alternative for his meaning is a good one.

Comment: @SomethingDark - a very amusing interpretation.

Comment: Just seeing the title - before clicking through to read the full question - the first thing that came to mind was "the shoemaker's children go barefoot", which means that after you've done your job all day for other people you don't want to do it at home too. (In your mechanic example, I suppose it would be "the mechanic's car is always broken down.")  I realize it's not what you're looking for, but now I'm curious: how many proverbs like this - with similar setups but completely different conclusions - are there?

Comment: @SomethingDark Is that what that means? I've been using it wrong. My intent was as it was written, as the meaning I thought it had is more appropriate for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I actually have no idea what it means; I've never heard that saying before, and Google comes up with nothing for "the baker never buys his bread." Literally zero results.

Comment: @MT_Head I feel that life, but the phrase as I was looking for is for IT and similar fields, where you don't get a ton of money, but at least you don't have to pay people to set up your computer and network at home.

Comment: @SomethingDark I noticed that. I can't even imagine where I read it, in a place that's untouched by Google. Maybe on Reddit, but searching there turned up nothing either.

Comment: @SomethingDark, I'd go along with that if the proverb said "the baker doesn't *eat* his own bread."

Comment: "Not invented here."

Comment: @SomethingDark Actually 268 results :P, but none are relevant, so it's to the same effect (https://www.google.com/search?q=the+baker+never+buys+his+bread&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22the+baker+never+buys+his+bread.%22). Is it even an idiom, since it's so uncommon?

Comment: @JFA - Actually, I'd say it goes both ways - a lot of my colleagues in IT actually have crappy old computers at home, and spouses/children with malware-infected rigs.  You get home after a long day of dealing with technological nonsense, and you don't necessarily want to face more of it at night.

Comment: There is the opposite: *The Cobbler's children have no shoes*. -[etymology](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159004/the-cobblers-children-have-no-shoes)

Comment: Saying he never buys **his** bread can be taken to mean that he doesn't like what _he_ bakes, so he buys bread from somebody else!  No wonder people misunderstand!

Comment: @JFA Before searching for an english proverb you should find out what the russian one means. Not a native speaker, but for me it sounded like "because he knows what's inside" or "he is sick of seeing bread all day". "he has bread, so he doesn't need to buy it" makes ofc sense too.

Comment: @Catija - I think your comment is the best answer here.

Comment: @Bobson Thanks :) I've added an expanded version as an answer.

Comment: @JFA -- Happy as a Gopher in Soft Dirt.

Comment: Russian here, but unfortunately unfamiliar with the expression. When I read it I understood it as "the baker never eats his own bread because he knows what kind of crap is in there."

Comment: @MishaRosnach That's why I put the question mark after Russian. I saw it on the internet and can't find it again, so I'm not sure what the origin is, but it's second or third hand at best. The idiom I'm looking for, though, as has been mentioned, is one that lines up with the explanation. As you can tell, the idiom does not have a clear meaning, so I'm looking for an idiom the meaning similar to the explanation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The proverb in English is "The baker never wants for bread."

Although this is not exactly well-known, the meaning is clear and shouldn't need an explanation.  *(sentence edited - see comment by Mar-Lou A)*

Example

> *Labour has a golden soil and the baker never wants for bread.*
>   - The Southern literary messenger
>   http://goo.gl/DDwv2G

---

Note:  **X never wants for Y** was once a common idiom. It has declined in use these days. *(sentence edited - see comment by Janus Bahs Jacquet)*

e.g. "His daughter is a spoiled brat. She never wants for anything."

Comment: The citation appears to be an English translation of the German proverb.I checked "The baker never wants for bread" and Google reveals [**only 3 results for this saying**](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ypGgVYymMqmO8Qexg4GwBw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22The+baker+never+wants+for+bread%22). Please provide a reference which "proves" this was once a common English proverb.

Comment: I have done a bit of research and I found nothing that supports your claim that "The baker never wants for bread" is a little-known *English* proverb. On the contrary, **it has never been an old English proverb**. See: [*A COLLECTION OF PROVERBS
OF ALL NATIONS ON BREAD AND BAKING*](http://www.breadculture.net/web/files/77/en/poslovice_o_hlebu.pdf) First published in 1924.

Comment: I would question the assertion that _X never wants for Y_ is **common**. It is an accepted meaning of the phrasal verb _want for_, but it’s hardly common—on the contrary, it’s rather formal and old-fashioned to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for your comment. It reminds me to be a bit more rigorous. I didn't actually claim it was common. I said what it was "in English", i.e. "in translation". Nevertheless you are right to pull me up and I have amended the following sentence in order to be clearer.

Comment: Nice try with making it seem I misunderstood. Your original post said: *Although this has fallen out of use* (it used to be common), which was later amended to: *Although this is little known nowadays* (it used to be well-known). The truth of the matter is that you discovered a good translation  of an unknown, possibly of German origin, proverb.

Comment: Just for fun, a proverb with a nearly opposite sense: "The shoemaker's children go barefoot."

Answer (score 3):

There is an English proverb (actually, frequently attributed as a [Chinese proverb](http://www.bartleby.com/73/484.html)) that is widely used that goes:

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

The nuance is not the same, but it does have the gestalt of elevating the destitute and feeding the hungry. You might get your point across without having to dissect if you substitute a fisherman or fishmonger for your baker.

> A man who knows how to fish never goes hungry.
>
> A fisherman never has to buy a meal.

Doesn't have quite the same ring to it, though.

Comment: I don't think these quite hit the nail on the head, the idea is that someone with these kind of physical skills may be poor and may be hungry, but at least they will never have to pay someone to do this sort of job.

Comment: Don't you mean "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a *day*..."? Otherwise that's a pretty impressive fish (or it's poison and he'll be dying soon!)

Comment: Thank you Sabre and Ben. You have brought honor to my post.

Comment: @Sabre You never know, it might be a fugu. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I have not been able to trace the OP's proverb, and not through lack of trying. The closest *English* proverb that I did find is said to originate from Norfolk

> **If you keep a fairy loaf you will never want bread**
>   <sub><sup>*[Encyclopedia of Fairies in World Folklore and Mythology](https://books.google.it/books?id=rUqpAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=If%20you%20keep%20a%20fairy%20loaf%20you%20will%20never%20want%20bread&source=bl&ots=POY-07gKHv&sig=r3z7EWH68naqJJA_BuWUJtr6Ces&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MBqhVdf2JMPpUtDMgcgC&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=If%20you%20keep%20a%20fairy%20loaf%20you%20will%20never%20want%20bread&f=false)* (2013)</sup></sub>

An older variation has

> **If you keep a fairy loaf in the house, you will never want for bread**.
>
> <sub>*[Signs, omens and superstitions](https://archive.org/stream/signsomensandsu00cielgoog/signsomensandsu00cielgoog_djvu.txt)* (1918) By Astra Cielo</sub>

A *fairy loaf*, also called a *Pharisee Loaf*, was the name given for *Fossil [echini](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/echini)*, a fossilized sea-urchin, which were sometimes discovered after ploughing the fields.

> "Pharisee" for "Fairy" seems to be a Sussex thing. Fossil echinoids which looked like bread loaves were called both "Fairy Loaves" and "Pharisee Loaves" there. They were once used as charms when baking to make the bread rise to the right shape.
>   Probably, "Pharisee" is just a corruption of the word "Fairy".
>
> <sub>[Leprechauns, fairies and little people](http://www.h2g2.com/forums/A148907/conversation/view/F19585/T644793/page/3)</sub>

An image of an [Echinoid](http://www.twmuseums.org.uk/geofinder/search/item.php?record=NEWHM:G125.44) shows how people might have been fooled into thinking these were ancient miniature loaves of bread

[image]

There is however a common Italian dialect proverb that goes

> (Piedmont) Chi a l'à un mestè per le man, a j manca mai pì pan
>   (Italian) Chi ha un mestiere in man, dappertutto trova pan
>   <sub>[Dizionario dei proverbi italiani e dialettali](https://books.google.it/books?id=vXlfAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=in%20man,%20An%20ga%20manca%20mai%20pan.&source=bl&ots=_t0eILEPCz&sig=yH8viDKTHWmHJpP9f9ySw8FNYO8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KOWgVfPtO4HaUt3Ps6gH&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=in%20man%2C%20An%20ga%20manca%20mai%20pan.&f=false)</sub>

Which loosely translated means:
**He who has a trade will never be short of bread**

A similar German proverb: *jegliches Handwerk nahrt seinen Mann*

The English equivalent is (which rhymes and makes perfect sense):

> **A trade in hand finds gold in every land**

Source: *[Dictionary of European Proverbs](https://books.google.it/books?id=86yPOGG3YfcC&pg=PT247&lpg=PT247&dq=Chi%20ha%20un%20mestiere%20in%20man,%20dappertutto%20trova%20pan&source=bl&ots=6uiOJ2Hxtu&sig=EuSxJmLvk0BhL-P5Hd6JPKwjQ-o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eD2jVau-GIjCywPOwKL4Cw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Chi%20ha%20un%20mestiere%20in%20man%2C%20dappertutto%20trova%20pan&f=false)*

Answer (score 3):

Converting my comment to an answer:

I would think the more appropriate phrasing to convey the meaning you want would be something like:

> *The baker never needs to buy bread.*

I can't think of a common English version of this idiom off the top of my head but I think this would be more understood than how you've currently translated it. The issue with the translation in your question is that the use of the word "his" can be unclear.

> *the baker never buys his bread*

This can be interpreted in two ways, the way you intend (I'm guessing) and another, more negative way:

1. The baker always has bread, so he doesn't need to buy the bread for *his table*.
2. The baker doesn't like *his own* bread, so he gets bread from another bakery.

My version of this statement removes the ambiguity and only allows the first interpretation.

Regardless of all of this, there's nothing in the English version that gives any implication that the baker is poor, only that his work gives him the bread he needs for the day.

I don't know the Russian saying or what the actual meaning of it is, but in English, there's a [sub-definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bread) of "bread" that implies all "food [or] sustenance", not strictly bread. It's most notably part of the *Lord's Prayer*

> *Give us this day our daily bread*

So, I suppose the concept of literal bread being the bare minimum for the more figurative bread could get you a little bit of that implication of surviving on the bare necessities of life.

Additionally, if you want to be pedantic, you could argue that, technically, he does pay for the ingredients, so he does still "buy" it to some degree.

---

Similar concept that I thought of when thinking through this answer:

- Don't go to the barber with the best haircut.

This is more similar to the second case I mentioned above... Barbers can scarcely be expected to cut their own hair, so the one with the best haircut is clearly not the best barber... it's the person who cut his hair.

Answer (score 1):

I have a dad who is a former breadman, and he would use the phrase "[the breadman] always brings home the bread." (usually referring to himself) It's not an exact match but it's similar enough. It's a similar idiom to the term "bringing home the bacon" referring to the primary money-earner of a household. You could see it as a morphism of that phrase.

Due to the U.S.'s capitalist economy, you might see the phrase "bringing home the bacon" as the equivalent, because although the primary money-earner of a household doesn't necessarily make the bacon, they generate the wealth which is used to buy it. I imagine there are many more laborers in the US who make references to this phrase when referring to their chosen profession. A butcher, for example, would use the phrase "Bringing home the bacon" as a direct subversion of the original meaning, referring to the literal bacon he/she/etc brings home, and not the money. However, for other working persons, it could be bringing home the orange juice, the ice cream, the TV's, the cars, or any other number of physical goods, as a morphed version of the original phrase.

In my dad's case, he didn't bake the bread though, he delivered it.

Comment: "The butcher always brings home the bacon"?

Comment: This isn't it at all.

Answer (score 1):

> If you become a chef, you will never go hungry.

Answer (score 0):

"When life gives you lemons, make lemonade!" It means when you have difficulties in life, use them to your advantage.

I don't know, but I did find an 1845 printing with your quote.  On page 402 it appears in a story that was translated from GERMAN into English. [Slight Causes. From the German of Zchokke (Translated for the Southern Literary Messenger)](https://books.google.com/books?id=XFIFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA402&lpg=PA402&dq=baker+never+wants+for+bread&source=bl&ots=YhnzKvEiwa&sig=uulwSZCnVJ5Bzz2M3p7Lc8txcnc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DZSgVZ39DYLh-QHP46SwCg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=baker%20never%20wants%20for%20bread&f=false)

German vs Russian

Comment: I disagree on this phrase being equivalent to the one in the question. “Making lemonade” means creating opportunities, while the baker consuming their own bread means that there's a necessity they don't have to worry about.

Comment: Yes, it's not the same.  We seem to be hard put to find something that is the same.  At least, I found it to be a translation from German. Though, you can't make bread without the ingredients.  Either way, it's a good saying.

Answer (score -2):

"Don't Get High On Your Own Supply" has a very different meaning but sounds quite similar. Instead of taking all the free bread you want the saying implies good business practice would preclude you from eating your own product. That or the saying is purely based on the effects of the drugs and therefore irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: This was the first thing to come to my mind upon reading the title, but the body of the question shows an opposite intent. Never get high on your own supply is business advice that would _discourage_ the baker from eating too much of his own bread.

Answer (score -3):

Well, the first one that come to mind, being a gamer is the saying

"...at least I have chicken..."

It is a reference to Leeroy Jenkins. It's a modern meme, of course. Only a select crowd will understand it, but it may be useful if you are speaking to such a person. I have used it a few times to convey the idea of being in a bad place and destitute but still having a small comfort, and it was understood in this context.

I found a similar idiom that is self explanatory, if not a bit sardonic; "A bad veterinarian never goes hungry."

"A blessing in disguise" is a more general, broad interpretation.

Or, simply, "Count your Blessings". It simply means to be appreciative of what one does have. That may be the context you are looking for.

"A fisherman never goes hungry", as mentioned, is one I have heard before. It means that one in their trade always has that need met; though it can be interpreted slightly differently.

Answer (score -4):

My mom is cuban and she's always saying this phrase "En casa del herrero cuchillo de palo", i think it means "In the blacksmith's house wooden knife". i dont know but i think its related to your question. I hope it's useful

Comment: I think this means something entirely different.

Comment: https://www.duolingo.com/comment/1296883/En-casa-de-herrero-cuchillo-de-palo